# Ruby dot parenthesis call syntax

Tags: ruby, function, syntax, parameters

I was reading the [jbuilder's README](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) and saw these code:

```
class Person
  # ... Class Definition ... #
  def to_builder
    Jbuilder.new do |person|
      person.(self, :name, :age)
    end
  end
end
```

I tried to replicate it myself, and it asks for a `call` method, so:

```
class Thing
   attr_accessor :name, :age

   def call(*args)
     puts args.inspect
   end
end

Thing.new.(:name, :age) # => [:name, :age]
```

So why is there a `self` in the `jbuilder` call?

Comment: I google searched for this after seeing Jbuilder's readme as well lol.  Thanks for figuring it out, what an odd and not-the-ruby-way syntax for a method call...

Answer (score 4):

`self` here is just a parameter passed to the Jbuilder's `call` method.

`Jbuilder` needs the instance of `person` (which is `self` in the code) and the attribute names (`:name` and `:age` in the code) to produce the json data.

Example:

```
class Thing
   attr_accessor :name, :age

   def call(*args)
     puts args.inspect
   end
end

class Bar
  def to_thing
    Thing.new.(self, :name, :age)
  end
end

Bar.new.to_thing
```