# How the '.call' method be triggered by a returning integer in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I encountered a code kata, it asks to implement a `add(n)` method which can chain multiple numbers then add them up, like:

```
add(1).(2).(3).(4).(5);  # => 15
```

When I first started，I thought it might involve `method_missing` method, so I firstly made a simplified version to see how the `*args` were handled when I was chaining a `.(n)` after a method which would return a integer, I chose `rand` to do this.

```
def method_missing(m, *args)
  p m
  p args
end

> rand(10).(9).(8)
# some other methods add empty array
:call
[9]
:call
[8]
 => [8]
```

Then I found the following chained `.(n)` just call `.call` method and take `n` as its parameter. Based on [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26580516/ruby-dot-parenthesis-call-syntax) I just rewrite the `call` method in `class Integer`:

```
class Integer
  def call(x)
    self + x
  end
end


def add(n)
  n
end
```

Then I get the result.

The question is I knew that the `.call` method is usually sent to a [Proc object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Method.html#method-i-call). But here the `add(n)` (as well as `rand` and other methods returning an integer) just simply returns a integer.

Why this can trigger `call` method? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.()` is just a shortcut for `.call()` Yes, the call method is usually used to run proc objects, but that doesn't make it anything special, just a regular method that a proc object has implemented. If you define it to do something else, the shortcut still works as normal

Comment: Thanks! I mistook that it's not an integer triggered `.call`, it's just I used `.()` method which is the shortcut for `call()`.